# '==' operator not found

Tags: c++, if-statement, operator-keyword

So apparently this prgoram is not working. Software tells me that the '==' operator is missing. Could some tell me what to do about this and explain why his/her solution works?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int var{ 0 };

    cout << "Bitte eine Ganzzahl eingeben: ";
    if ((cin >> var) == false) {
        cerr << "Falsche Eingabe - Keine Zahl\n";
        exit(1);
    }


    system("pause");
    //return 0;
}
```

And while we're at it. Why is it possible to execute 'cin' in the if statemant? I would have used 'cin' before the if statemant.

Comment: This [compiles and runs](https://ideone.com/y77h9a) fine for me.

Comment: @MooseBoys it compiles only in pre-C++11, as it will use the `void*` to `bool` implicit conversion.

Comment: @MooseBoys: It will work with an outdated standard library (where the stream converts to a pointer type rather than `bool`), but not a modern one (with an explicit conversion to `bool`).

Comment: Apparently IDEOne is not compliant - it's set to C++14 mode and still works.  Sure enough cl.exe complains though.

Comment: First sentence means: Input an Integer. Second one means: Wrong input. I don't think that should be relevant though,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In modern C++, the status of a stream can be tested using an `explicit operator bool`. This means that it can be used directly as the condition in an `if` statement, but can't be implicitly converted to `bool` to compare with `false`. So you'd need the more idiomatic

```
if (cin >> var)
```

to test the status.

> Why is it possible to execute 'cin' in the if statemant?

Because the condition can be any expression, as long as it has a result that can be converted to `bool`. The `>>` operator returns a reference to the stream, which can be converted via the operator I described above.

Answer (score 1):

First `cin` is not something that you execute, like the `print` command of some other languages. It is an object of class *istream*  that represents the standard input stream of chars.

The operator `>>` extracts formatted input from such streams. Its prototype is something like

```
istream& operator>> (int& val);
```

meaning it returns a reference to the istream itself, so you can chain operations like

```
cin >> foo >> bar;
```

so you can't compare the result of `cin >> foo`, which is a reference, to the constant `false`.

On the other hand, the operator "!" is overloaded and means the same thing as `fail`, so you can check that an operation succeeds like this

```
if ( ! (cin >> var) ) {
   cerr << "something is going wrong" << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::istream` has conversion operator to `bool`, but it has to be explicit (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool):

```
explicit operator bool() const;
```

You can use an explicit conversion operator:

```
if ( (bool)(cin >> var) == false) {
    cerr << "Falsche Eingabe - Keine Zahl\n";
}
```

or simply use:

```
if ( !(cin >> var) ) {
    cerr << "Falsche Eingabe - Keine Zahl\n";
}
```